# Can I import data from previous package of my UWP app?

Tags: uwp

I need to change the publisher name of my UWP application for compliance reasons. I see that changing the publisher name (by changing the signing certificate) changes the application package name.

Now I would like to import user settings and data from the previous package of the app so as not cause disruption to the users. It doesn't look like Windows provides any way to do this.

I might be able to write some code to copy required files from the old package directory (essentially the LocalState directory), but I can't figure out how to restore the recently used files list. I'm using StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList, and this seems to return the data even if I delete everything from the application package directory. Does anyone know where Windows stores the MRU file list?

Answer (score 0):

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemmostrecentlyusedlist) has mentioned the relevant things:

> We recommend that you store the tokens that are returned by StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.Add and StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add so that you can use them to retrieve the respective list entry for the item that you added.

So, you could save the token in localsettings.

Since you said 'You're able to write some code to copy required files from the old package directory (essentially the LocalState directory)'. You could get the relevant thing from local folder. Then, with this way, you did not need to think about where Windows stores the MRU file list.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that they're stored in the the registry.